# Estancado con ejemplo relativamente sencillo, ¿cómo avanzar?

Tags: python-3.x

buenas noches. Soy nuevo en esto de programación, y estoy intentando resolver el siguiente caso:

Si el content_rating de la película es "G" o "PG", llamar send_email_to_fans() con the movie's tittle.

Así voy:

```
import csv

with open('movie_metadata.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=',',quotechar=',',
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for now in reader:
        print(row)

if content_rating==“G” or content_rating==“PG”
    def send_email_to_fans(movie_title)
    res = {"success": random.choice([True, False]), "response_id": random.randint()}
```

Lo que sé es que primero debo hacer un print, para ver qué res[n] voy a trabajar.
movie_tittle es la columna **12**.Y content_rating la **22**.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo puedo escribir esto en código? Entiendo que posteriormente debería hacer otro if. O no sé si estoy muy perdido. Por eso estoy aquí. Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes usar pandas

Comment: Si pudieras orientarme un poco, te lo agradecería millones. @Christian

Comment: Si dentro de 8 horas nadie te responde lo haré yo (es hora de dormir, lo siento)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Seguro estaré despierto hasta entonces. ¡Descansa! Ojalá puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Lo siento por demorarme. Para dar una respuesta necesito saber cual es tu csv